# error with serialization with protobuf

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to serialize a structure with protobuf. after many hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong I decided to test the google's example and it didn't worked as well

I have the following protocol from google (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial):

```
package tutorial;
option java_package = "com.example.tutorial";
option java_outer_classname = "AddressBookProtos";

message Person {
    required string name = 1;
    required int32 id = 2;
    optional string email = 3;
    repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;

    enum PhoneType {
        MOBILE = 0;
        HOME = 1;
        WORK = 2;
    }

    message PhoneNumber {
        required string number = 1;
        optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
    }
}

message AddressBook {
    repeated Person person = 1;
}
```

and I'm trying to serialize it with:

```
Person john = Person.newBuilder()   
    .setId(1234)
    .setName("John Doe")
    .setEmail("jdoe@example.com")
    .addPhone(
        Person.PhoneNumber.newBuilder()
            .setNumber("555-4321")
            .setType(Person.PhoneType.HOME))
    .build();
```

> byte[] serialized = john.toByteArray();

and I get "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses."

Thanks;

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Did you use a version of `protoc` that matched the library you are using?

Comment: I was using different versions of protobuf... Thanks a lot Marc!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As Marc said, A mismatch in Protocol Buffer versions will give you this exact message. In particular if

- The .proto definition is converted to java using the 2.4.3 (or earlier) protoc.exe
- You use the 2.5.0 protobuffers library

you will get this message in many methods (e.g. getParserForType, getUnknownFields) of class **GeneratedMessage**. There are no doubt other potential mismatch's that will cause this error

---

With **protocol buffers 2.5.0** it is **essential** you **regenerate** all java classes with the 2.5.0 version of protoc (or on windows protoc.exe).

---

If you do the reverse - run code generated by **protoc version 2.5** with the libraries for **protocol buffers version 2.4**. You will get the following message

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class xxx.xxx.xx.. 
overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
```

Comment: But I get this message even protobuf and java lib are 2.5.0

Comment: @Adio did you generate protobuf class with 2.5.0. This message occurs when the protobuf-java class is generated from the .proto definition with a prior version of java. I will update my answer to make this clearer

Comment: This is sort of amazing. I was planning to use protocol buffers to eliminate version dependencies and now I don't have anything working because protoc is in Ubuntu of version 2.4.1 and protobuf-java in the project has version 2.5.0. Plus message "This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses" is really lousy in describing real reason for a problem.

Comment: I'm running in same problem. Based on @BruceMartin mention I can confirm that my Ubuntu version running on proto V3.0.0 where In my source code  I'm using lower [V2.6.1](https://github.com/julienr/protobuf-android). I'm really stuck here as I don't see any source code that build .so for V3.0.0. Any suggestion here, what can be done?

Comment: I have not looked atV3.0.0, but do you have the Proto definition's (may have a .proto extension) ???. If you do, you should be able to run a protoc to regenerate interface files

Comment: @BruceMartin I got to build for **3.0.0-beta-1** and same I install on my system. So now generated lib and .h, .cc file refer same version "3.0.0-beta-1"..but still same facing issue. Any suggestion here!

Comment: What Error messages are you getting and where are you getting them ???, you might be better off asking a question with all the details