# Protobufs - 'supposed to be overridden by subclasses' exception

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I've got a problem with Google Protocol Buffers. The java class compiled using protoc throws exceptions during conversion to byte array.

Here is the example code:

```
byte[] raw = pbCard.toByteArray(); 
// PbCard.Card is an instance of a protoc-generated class.
```

This results in an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.
```

This kind of behaviour was diagnosed by many to be a **problem with protoc versions**. When using java classes generated using protoc < 2.5.0 and including a java library 2.5.0, this exception will be generated.

**Links:**

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=493

[error with serialization with protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908268/error-with-serialization-with-protobuf)

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.protocol-buffers.general/9588

[Protobuf 2.5.0 bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130886/protobuf-2-5-0-bug)

However, in my case **both** the protoc and java library are in **version 2.5.0**.

```
eipifi@vaio:~$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.5.0
```

And the included jar:

```
eipifi@vaio:~$ sha1sum protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar 
a10732c76bfacdbd633a7eb0f7968b1059a65dfa  protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
```

No older version of protobufs was ever present on my machine. All java classes were generated on this machine and were not moved from an older project.

What am I missing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you supply the proto definition / generated code ???